# Android Ignition POM Error

Tags: android, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, droid-fu

I am new to all things maven and ignition. I am attempting to set up ignition-core as a library project to link to a new project. However the ignition-core pom has this error...

Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Could not find artifact com.github.ignition:ignition:pom:0.3-SNAPSHOT and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

How can I resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ignition](https://github.com/kaeppler/ignition) is a [multi-module project](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation) that consist of a group of projects which has inter-module dependencies with each other:

```
ignition/
  ignition-core/
    ignition-core-lib/
    ignition-core-samples/
    ignition-core-tests/
    pom.xml
  ignition-location/
    ignition-location-lib/
    ignition-location-samples/
    ignition-location-tests/
    pom.xml
  ignition-support/
    ignition-support-lib/
    ignition-support-samples/
    pom.xml
  pom.xml
```

Suppose you use Eclipse and has m2e and m2e-android plugins installed. You need import all projects as a group into Eclipse by using `File -> Import ... -> Maven -> Existing Maven Projects` and choose ignition/ as the root project folder.

Without modifying the pom.xml (break the structure of multi-module projects), you can't import and use ignition-core/ independently in Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you yorkw. I appreciate your answer.